Black stripe Artifacts when rendering
I am relatively new to blender and I have a wooden texture table that looks perfectly fine in viewport shading: 
However, the cycles rendered picture looks like this: 
Looks like artifacts at the edges of that table and also a few on the chairs.
The rendered model was at over 1k samples when the screenshot was taken.
Things I have already considered / done:

Tried rendering with and without Denoise. Same result.

Tried rendering without the normal map texture and without any normal mapping at all. Same result.

There are no texture duplicates.


What else could be a possible cause or solution to this problem ?
Your help is greatly appreciated !
Update: Seems something was kinda messed up with the textures. After selecting all faces in the UV Editor and applying Smart UV Project the texture looks extremely ugly but the black spots are gone:
https://imgur.com/a/6OnNA5M (sorry for the noise, had to upload it on imgur, cause the file size was too big here)

hello could you please share your file? Don't forget to pack your images if you've used some images

can you share the file (at least the table and its image texture) so that we can understand what was the problem?

Yes, no problem. The complete project file is way too big but the table I downloaded from CGTrader link

I need a login, can you please just share the table only (with the image packed)? https://blend-exchange.com/

The compressed archive is 50MB and on blend exchange they allow 30MB max.
Please download it from here: https://file.io/e2Wo3WEgUqIt

So, right now the problem seems solved.
I have marked all edges as seams and then unwrapped the texture or applied Smart UV Project.
This is the result now:

